# WebSocket on Win EC7 / EC2013?

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

has anyone experience using WebSocket protocol in Win EC7 / EC2013?
Are there browser which support WebSockets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Compact 2013 the browser has been "streamlined" (marketing version of "removed" in plain English) and the one in Compact 7 lags way behind desktop and mobile browsers in terms of features.
There are some commercial solutions. 
One from bsquare:
http://www.bsquare.com/products/html5-rendering-engine
the other from zebra (they have been acquired by motorola solutions, so I'm not sure if the software is still available)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check these out. Found another one, too: zetakey.com offers a commercial HTML5 browser.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I mixed the names :)